# Relative URL in node.js (i18in)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, i18next

I want to add relative URL instead of using SERVER_URL var in this expression in file i18in.js
So, i want to make URL path relative, not absolute. How can i do that? thank you in advance!

```
const SERVER_URL = 'http://BLABLABLA/api'

const NextI18NextInitial = new NextI18Next({
  backend: {
    loadPath:  `${SERVER_URL}/getcontent/{{lng}}/${Math.round(Math.random()* 10000000)}`,
  }
})
```

Comment: Just wondering, what does it do if you specify `loadPath` as `/getcontent/{{lng}}/...`? I.e. remove the SERVER_URL.

Comment: My devopser says, that it return an error ( but i know php/javascript as well, and i think, that there must be some global functions like __FILE__, __DIR__. Maybe will try to change devoper, and will fixed)))